# Rails checking if an object is also assigned to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in my Rails application I've got a n:m relation between movies and tags. (has_and_belongs_to_many)

So each tag can be assign to several movies.

Now when I add new tags to a movie I want to check If this Tag is already assigned to this movie.

What is the esiest way in rails to check if there is a relation ship between the tag and the movie?

I fetch the tag with:

```
@tagfound = Tag.where("tagname = ?", data[:tagname])
```

The List with all Tags from the movie can be fetched with this:

```
@vid.tags
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Note: `where(tagname: data[:tagname])` is a more concise way of expressing this.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to check.  You can simply do this

```
movie.tags = [array, of, tags]
movie.save   # note, you don't need to save.  The line above saves.
```

or

```
movie.tag_ids = [1,2,3,4]
movie.save   # note, you don't need to save.  The line above saves.
```

and that will take care of it setting new tags and removing the ones that are no longer connected.  Good for checkbox UI or a tokenizer.

To answer your question, to find if a movie has a tag, you can do this

```
tag.in?(movie.tags)
```

And this is the way to add a single

```
movie.tags << tag unless tag.in?(movie.tags)
```

[EDIT]
If you do this

```
movie.update_attributes(movie_params)
```

and one of the params is the tag_ids, the movie will only save the new tags if it is valid (no other errors).

Comment: This is such a neat answer, @swards. I love Ruby and rails for the kind of code you wrote in the last line :)

Comment: On thing, @swards. I tried this in a rails console and the statement `movie.tag_ids = [1,2,3,4]`, saved the result to the database without doing `movie.save`. Why such behaviour?

Comment: Yeah, surprising to me too.  In practice, I don't think it's a problem.  If you are saving a movie and want to check if it's valid first, use the form params and update it all through `update_attrbutes(movie_params)` and it won't save the tags if the movie has errors.  Added this to the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 ways you can do this.

1. Check if @tagfound is included in @vid.tags

   `@vid.tags.include? @tagfound`
2. Add the tag & call uniq after.

   `@vid.tags << @tagfound
    @vid.tags.uniq!`